# How much Abstract Algebra is needed to study Differential Geometry in modern fashion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, book-recommendation

I ask this question mainly because in the book "INTRODUCTION TO SMOOTH MANIFOLDS" by John Lee, it was stated that the reader is expected to have understanding in "fundamental group" and "covering space". When I google these terms, I find they are concepts in Modern Algebra which is a biggest gap in my Math knowledge.

Personally, I am not motivated to learn Pure mathematics in a most rigorous manner. I only want to learn the basics of some pure maths so that I can read the text that make use of them. So far, I have read 300 pages of point set topology,400 pages of real analysis, 300pages of functional analysis, but none for abstract algebra.

I know that Lee's "INTRODUCTION TO TOPOLOGICAL MANIFOLD" covered all I need for his book on Smooth Manifold. But, even that seems to expect basic knowledge in Group theory.

https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441979391（Lee's "INTRODUCTION TO TOPOLOGICAL MANIFOLD“）

Can someone recommend me a readable book that allows me to quickly go through the basics of abstract algebra so that I can start with Lee's book on toplogical manifold? 500 pages of abstract algebra seem too intimidating.

Comment: The notions of "fundamental group" and "covering space" belong to (algebraic) topology not algebra. These topics are covered in chapter 1 of  [Algebraic Topology by Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Comment: The group theory background you need for reading my _Introduction to Topological Manifolds_ is summarized in Appendix C of that book. If you need more detailed explanations of the material discussed there, the beginning of the appendix suggests two undergraduate algebra books that you could refer to: Herstein's _Abstract Algebra_ or Hungerford's _Abstract Algebra: An Introduction_.

Comment: If you want to study a book in pure mathematics, then you should be motivated to study pure mathematics. Studying group theory and studying differential geometry is very similar in this respect, although they are of a different area in pure mathematics. On the web there are excellent lecture notes on abstract algebra, much less than $500$ pages long (have a look with google).